# bug of a string terminator in C

Tags: c, string

I have this data struct:

```
struct WordCounter
{
  char *word;
  int word_count;
  struct WordCounter *pNext;                        /* Pointer to the next word counter in the list */
};
```

This struct is used to count the words found in a file.
I have this method that give me the current word in the linked list, and another method that give her count:

```
char* giveWord(struct WordCounter *pWordcounter){  // return current word of the linked list
    return pWordcounter->word;
}

int giveCounter (struct WordCounter *pCounter){
    int tempcount = pCounter -> word_count;
   return tempcount;
    
}
```

What I'm interested in is copying the words into new array, for some things I need to do after this part of the code, but I have a strange error, beacuse when i print the word with %s the word is correct, but if i call the second element of the array i get the separator, did you know why? and how i can solve it? That's the code:

```
char* wordy[100];  // temp array for the copy of a single word

pCounter = pStart;  // pStart is a pointer to the first element of my linked list
exactly_word = malloc(sizeof(char)*num_car);  // this array collect all the words, num_car is the total characters of all the worlds in the linked list

int indice = 0;
int indice_parole = 0;
for(int x=0; x<readed_nd_word;x++){    // readed_nd_word is for how much word there are in the linked list
    counters[x] = giveCounter(pCounter);
    strcat(wordy,giveWord(pCounter));
    printf("WORDY: %s \n",wordy);       // this print is ok 

    if(wordy[1] == 0){
        printf("is 0");  // the bug!!
    }
    while(wordy[indice]!= 0){
        printf("Char to insert %c \n",wordy[indice]);
        exactly_word[indice_parole] = wordy[indice];
        indice_parole++;
        indice++;
    }

    pCounter = pCounter -> pNext;  // move to the next word
    memset(wordy,0,100);  // lets clean the temp array for the next word
    indice = 0;
    exactly_word[indice_parole] = '\0';      // after each word i need a terminator
    indice_parole;
    
}
```

More precisely wordy on the first iteration contains the word "one" which is printed in full by printf. But if I call wordy[1] I find the terminator, how is that possible? the printf with the %s should stop at the first terminator.
Why wordy[1] is 0, but the print before, don't stop at first char?

Any idea to how i can solve this?
P.s. i know that i have to terminate the loop when pCounter is Null, but is a secondary problem i guess.

Input: in the linked list there are "one", "word", "hi"
At the first iteration of the for loop printf of wordy is "one"
But printf(wordy[1]) print "is 0".

The output should copy char by char the word "one" into exactly_word, this for each string in the linked list. So at first iteration of loop for i exactly word sould contain "one \0" at second "one \0 word \0" etc..

Comment: Please provide sample input, output and expected output. Please add this as formatted text instead of describing what you get.

Comment: `strcat(wordy...` Your compiler should warn you. `wordy` is an array of pointers which decays to `char**` while `strcat` expects a `char*`. Also you don't initialize it before you first concatenate a string to it. That will cause undefined behaviour even if you fix the type to `char[]`

Comment: @Gerhardh yep i get this warning, how i can solve it?

Comment: Make it `char wordy[100] = {0};` And importantly: Handly all warnings before you run the code. Many problems are already reported by the compiler.

Comment: To explain a bit more: `wordy[1]` is not addressing the second byte but byte 4 or 8 depending on your size of pointers. Your word `one` well fits into the space for first pointer.